# Purchase and Download

Tags: elementary-website, download

I have a debit card and I cannot purchase elementary OS.

I made a donation of 10 $ trough PayPal.

How can I now have access to the download? Thanks for the support.

Best regards,
Valter

Answer (score 2):

If you type 0 in the Custom box, the Purchase button turns into a Download button.

[image]

Comment: It's pay what you want. That means From $0 and up to whatever.