# Where is the OS?

Tags: system-installation

I have donated and downloaded your iso file which is a corrupt archive not able to be opened or imaged to USB, DVD, or any other media. You have no support or office phone number and no immediate means of contacting you. I guess I fell for the scam. The reason you require donation to download is evident, it is a scam.

I will be digging deep into this and contacting authorities to inform them of the scam.

If this is not a scam post a number to contact support or accounting for refunds.

Comment: Give this tutorial a try: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-install-elementary-os/358#358 (particularly Step 2 - Writing to the bootable media.) . If you believe you got a corrupt download, you can redownload it by typing 0 in the donation box (like https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21451/purchase-and-download/21452#21452)

Comment: I am not the problem the file is. I have re-downloaded several times from multiple mirrors all the same file.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by mirrors? As you can read here, there are no mirrors for downloading elementary OS https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28722/is-there-a-mirror-site-for-elementary-os. In any case, did you try setting up a bootable USB drive using the downloaded file?

Comment: Here's a quick video tutorial, and a really detailed written guide about setting up a bootable drive and installing the OS https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I'm just a Elementary OS user (quite fresh like yourself, only a few hours).

How did you flash the image to a USB drive? Did you use any application such as Rufus or Etcher? If not, you can try Etcher:

https://etcher.download/

I'm afraid you're overreacting a little bit btw...